# Best way to handle shooting in top down multiplayer game similar to Diep.io?

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, lidgren

Im using Unity with Lidgren networking library(server - client architecture) to develop game with perspective and look similar to Diep.io.

I trying to make shooting smooth on both sides, however, because of latency, if client is moving while shooting, client can see that bullet is created a bit further from player(last position that server received from client).

Currently to shoot, client sends packet to server, and server creates bullet at client position.

How does games like Diep.io handles shooting without any noticeable delay? 
How would you handle shooting in game similar to Diep.io?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not experienced in multiplayer development more than a beginner level, but here's my 2 cents.

You may be able to handle the bullet latency to some degree by following the advice in this tutorial.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/adding-multiplayer-shooting

If you look at the script a bit down the page, they have a part that says.

```
// This [Command] code is called on the Client …
// … but it is run on the Server!
[Command]
void CmdFire()
```

The library you use might have a similar method where it can be called on the client but run on the server.

Other than that, I'm a bit curious as to why you don't use the built-in unity multiplayer functionality? It has both a low level and a high level API.

Comment: This technique still have to deal with latency, command must be sent to server from client. Also I using Lidgren instead of Unity built-in networking because, Unet looks like more complicated to me(maybe it isn't) and not everything worked as I expected, maybe later I will try move to Unet, but for now Lidgren is enough.

Comment: It has to deal with latency yes, cant avoid that completely. But as you seem to also suggest now, experimenting with putting the responsibility on either client or server, might help you discover what works best latency wise. I believe Unitys built in solution is made around Unitys component system, to make it as easy as possible to use. But a tutorial might be warranted to ease down the learning curve.